# Unidentified index when I use htaccess file in custom page PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to get a pretty URL in PHP using a . htaccess file. The code for the . htaccess file is as below

```
RewriteEngine On  
 RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?post_url=$1  
 RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post.php?post_url=$1
```

The problem is that it gives out an error of unidentified index for the post_url link in the $_GET variable.

Comment: please, give an example url of what pretty url you want and the final url you need. In this case I'll be able to understand what goes wrong. If you want to find out reasons on your own, sometimes, this tool can help: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Guess: `MultiViews` is active, so no rewriting happened in the first place, but Apache just served the `post.php` file, based on the partial overlap of that file name with any `post/...` path. Try and disable it.

Comment: I want to change a URL like: localhost/project/post.php?post_url=custom-url to: localhost/project/post/custom-url